# jQuery selector to apply a class in a list

Tags: jquery

I've a nested list, I don't know how much levels will have and I need to mark some `<li />` with `class="selected"`... Its better if I show you and example of my generated HTML code from PHP. I can only know one of the `<li />` that will have the class.

```
<div id="submenu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                        <li class="selected"><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And what I want is add classes to the parent lists, the desired output:

```
<div id="submenu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
        <li class="selected">
            <a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
            <ul>
                <li class="selected">
                    <a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                        <li class="selected"><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Remember that is a nested list and we don't know how much levels will be.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: So... what exactly do you want jQuery to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this

```
$('#submenu .selected').parentsUntil('#submenu').filter('li').addClass('selected');
```

Note: some other answers don't use `parentsUntil` and will walk all the way up the DOM heirarchy.  That's OK if you don't expect any other parent nodes to be `li`, but I think it's safer to limit jquery to your menu.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
$('li.selected').parents('li').addClass('selected');
```

Working example:

> http://jsfiddle.net/Rrb9P/

Answer (score 1):

The `.parentsUntil()` solution is a good one.

Here's another possible way to do it:

```
$('#submenu li:has(.selected)').addClass('selected');
```

This uses the [`has-selector`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector to get all `<li>` elements under `#submenu` that have a nested `selected` class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("li.selected").parents("li").addClass("selected");
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use jquery to do this? Couldn't you just figure out what page you were on with PHP and add the class with PHP? You would then make sure the highlight showed up even if someone had javascript turned off.

Comment: I'm using a recursive tree from an array. I check for the id of the selected but when it's found, some list are already printed. ;(